# MyEclipse How to update the local dependency jars while the remote repo jars are covered?

Tags: java, maven, myeclipse

For some reason, the jar GAV in local pom.xml can't be changed,like a snapshot, its version is always 1.0-SNAPSHOT.

But in the remote repo, it may be covered by other mates.

For the index is not changed, the MyEclipse can't update to the latest jar,and comes somes problems.

I konw that it can update to the latest jar in IDEA,how should I do in MyEclipse?

Comment: I don't understand the question. What do you mean by "in local pom.xml can't be changed"? Do you mean that the pom.xml file can't be edited or if you edit it, it returns to its previous state?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the m2e-Plugin you can update the maven dependencies of the project via Alt-F5 and then set the check mark on 'Force Update of Snapshots/Releases'